# How to uninstall a Firefox extension from command line?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have installed Firefox extension by double clicking `abc.xpi` file. Now I want to know where those files are copied, so that I can delete them. Or any other way to uninstall an extension except by going to Addons & then uninstalling it manually. I want to uninstall it programmatically.

Comment: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/05/workaround-to-manually-uninstall-remove-or-delete-firefox-addon-with-add-ons-uninstall-button-disabled/ maybe helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files created as part of the extension installation process are stored within the Firefox profile which you were using at the time. If you aren't aware of setting up more than one profile, you're probably using the "default" one which you got when you installed Firefox. Messing around with stuff within the profile directory can be extremely unwise, but if you want to try it you might want to think about:

- locating the profile directory - this will depend on your operating system, but looking under the directory specified in the environment variable `USERPROFILE` would be a good start
- finding the id for the extension you wish to remove
- removing the subdirectory corresponding to the extension id under the `extensions` directory within the profile
- remove the reference to the extension from the `extensions.ini` file
- possibly remove the `extensions.rdf` file completely, to allow it to be regenerated

I am currently unaware of an automated way of doing this from the command line, if you don't want to do it yourself, but there might be tools out there to do it for you.